# How to sum every N rows over a Window in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have tried different window functions to do this exercise, without success. Can anyone think of a different approach? Thought of adding and index column or an r_number.

| year | month | week | item | department | state | sales | sum(sales)_2wks | sum(sales)_4wks | sum(sales)_6wks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | TX | $100 | $250 | $680 | $1380 |
| 2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | TX | $150 | $250 | $680 | $1380 |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | TX | $200 | $430 | $680 | $1380 |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | TX | $230 | $430 | $680 | $1380 |
| 2020 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 | TX | $400 | $700 | $1050 | $1380 |
| 2020 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 1 | TX | $300 | $700 | $1050 | $1380 |
| 2020 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 1 | TX | $250 | $350 | $1050 | $1200 |
| 2020 | 1 | 8 | 1 | 1 | TX | $100 | $350 | $1050 | $1200 |
| 2020 | 1 | 9 | 1 | 1 | TX | $200 | $400 | $850 | $1200 |
| 2020 | 1 | 10 | 1 | 1 | TX | $200 | $400 | $850 | $1200 |
| 2020 | 1 | 11 | 1 | 1 | TX | $300 | $450 | $850 | $1200 |
| 2020 | 1 | 11 | 1 | 1 | TX | $150 | $450 | $850 | $1200 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution is good, just that row_number will give a false impression if we have multiple rows for same week, because the modulus(row_number/2) should be same for the same week rows.
Instead, prefer using dense_rank() over row_number() and rank() functions for obvious reasons.

```
val sales_data = Seq((2020,1,1,"1","1","TX",100),
                       (2020,1,1,"1","1","TX",150),
                       (2020,1,2,"1","1","TX",150),
                       (2020,1,3,"1","1","TX",200),
                       (2020,1,4,"1","1","TX",230),
                       (2020,1,5,"1","1","TX",400),
                       (2020,1,6,"1","1","TX",300),
                       (2020,1,7,"1","1","TX",250),
                       (2020,1,8,"1","1","TX",100),
                       (2020,1,9,"1","1","TX",200),
                       (2020,1,10,"1","1","TX",200),
                       (2020,1,11,"1","1","TX",300),
                       (2020,1,11,"1","1","TX",150))
                       
  //Calculate moving sales for 2 weeks, 4 weeks, 6 weeks
                               
  val sales_df = sales_data.toDF("year", "month", "week", "item", "dept", "state", "sale")
//  sales_df.show
  
  sales_df.withColumn("row_no", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("item", "state","dept").orderBy("year", "month", "week"))-1)
          .withColumn("sum(sales)_2wks", sum($"sale").over(Window.partitionBy($"item", $"state",$"dept", ($"row_no"/2).cast("int"))))
          .withColumn("sum(sales)_3wks", sum($"sale").over(Window.partitionBy($"item", $"state",$"dept", ($"row_no"/3).cast("int"))))
          .withColumn("sum(sales)_4wks", sum($"sale").over(Window.partitionBy($"item", $"state",$"dept", ($"row_no"/4).cast("int"))))
          .withColumn("sum(sales)_6wks", sum($"sale").over(Window.partitionBy($"item", $"state",$"dept", ($"row_no"/6).cast("int"))))
          .show
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign row numbers, round them to the nearest 2/4/6 and use that as a partitioning column to sum over a window:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = df.withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('item', 'department', 'state').orderBy('year', 'month', 'week')) - 1
).withColumn(
    'sum_2wks', 
    F.sum('sales').over(Window.partitionBy('item', 'department', 'state', (F.col('rn') / 2).cast('int')))
).withColumn(
    'sum_4wks', 
    F.sum('sales').over(Window.partitionBy('item', 'department', 'state', (F.col('rn') / 4).cast('int')))
).withColumn(
    'sum_6wks', 
    F.sum('sales').over(Window.partitionBy('item', 'department', 'state', (F.col('rn') / 6).cast('int')))
)

result.show()
+----+-----+----+----+----------+-----+-----+---+--------+--------+--------+
|year|month|week|item|department|state|sales| rn|sum_2wks|sum_4wks|sum_6wks|
+----+-----+----+----+----------+-----+-----+---+--------+--------+--------+
|2020|    1|   1|   1|         1|   TX|  100|  0|     250|     680|    1380|
|2020|    1|   2|   1|         1|   TX|  150|  1|     250|     680|    1380|
|2020|    1|   3|   1|         1|   TX|  200|  2|     430|     680|    1380|
|2020|    1|   4|   1|         1|   TX|  230|  3|     430|     680|    1380|
|2020|    1|   5|   1|         1|   TX|  400|  4|     700|    1050|    1380|
|2020|    1|   6|   1|         1|   TX|  300|  5|     700|    1050|    1380|
|2020|    1|   7|   1|         1|   TX|  250|  6|     350|    1050|    1200|
|2020|    1|   8|   1|         1|   TX|  100|  7|     350|    1050|    1200|
|2020|    1|   9|   1|         1|   TX|  200|  8|     400|     850|    1200|
|2020|    1|  10|   1|         1|   TX|  200|  9|     400|     850|    1200|
|2020|    1|  11|   1|         1|   TX|  300| 10|     450|     850|    1200|
|2020|    1|  12|   1|         1|   TX|  150| 11|     450|     850|    1200|
+----+-----+----+----+----------+-----+-----+---+--------+--------+--------+
```